# debug.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: android, find, android-keystore

I didn't have any problem with opening my android project until I installed new Windows 10. After installing new windows I installed new Android studio too. And when I open project and sync it it says:
[image]
My earlier Windows's user's name was in cyrillic alphabet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue yesterday after moving the Android studio location from C: drive to E: drive. I was following this post - http://www.littlecpu.com/android-studio-c-drive.

To fix this issue goto - 
Build < Toggle View < Click "Run with --scan"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I moved my android project to new windows installation.

Cleaning project and re-building worked just fine for me.

1. Goto Build > Clean Project
2. Build again